# Python Selenium find Chrome element with attrid (not id)?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

I have a website (private, sorry) that I'm trying to pull some text from.
The relevant line, which is nested in a row of a table, when I inspect Chrome is as follows:

```
<div id="dataGeneral" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
  <table class="someClassName">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="*someOtherClassName*" attrid="com.intranet.state"> TextNeeded </td>
```

I have been able to get the above *TextNeeded* via full xPath, but is very unstable and most times leads to an error (no such element: Unable to locate element....)

What other method can I use to reliably pull this text? I've tried driver.find_elemend_by_id (and all the other options) using the above attrid, but this also says no such element.

Is there a way to maybe drill down from the table id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find this specific locator, use xpath:

```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td/a[contains(text(), "TextNeeded")]')
```

To get a text from this row use:

```
 text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(@attrid,'com.intranet.state')]").text
```

Comment: Thanks! Your second option seems to be doing the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='dataGeneral']/td[@class='someOtherClassName']")))
print(element.text)
```

Following imports needed:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```